# How to get the count for each taxonomy term

Tags: php, menus, customization, terms, count

I know it is `$term[0]->count;`

However, my terms are placed in the custom menu plugin. My terms are currently structured as

```
Parent
  Child
Parent
  Child
```

How do I append the term count of each term? I have been searching all over and haven't found a solution. My output should be:

```
Parent(2)
  Child(1)
Parent(5)
  Child(2)
```

I am still at a lost on how to approach this. So any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: If someone knows where to find the file for the custom menu widget, I think I can edit its output.

Comment: Which 'custom menu plugin' are you using?

Comment: The wordpress default. EDIT: Sorry, it's a widget.

Comment: The default WordPress widgets are located in the `\wp-includes\default-widgets.php` file. Any changes you make to the file will be overwritten each time WordPress updates.